# android edittext and multiple checkboxes

Tags: android

I need an editText and 10 checkboxes. On android phone I also need to have a scrollview. I mean I need to see the checkboxez in a scroll. How to do that?

Can someone post an layout example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <EditText id ="@+id/edittext1"
 android:text="EditText 1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
 <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout 
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/checkboxtest"/>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/checkboxtest"/>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/checkboxtest"/><CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/checkboxtest"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

add all your component to scrollview

```
<ScrollView....>
<LinearLayout..>
    <EditText />
    <CheckBox />
    <CheckBox />
    <CheckBox />
    <CheckBox />
    .
    .
    </LinearLayout..>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thnx, i don't think we need to copy n paste all code... he/she can understand by this...